# How can I add custom type on third-party module?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript

I'm programming for backend with node.js and typescript.

I installed 'mysql' module and '@types/mysql' module also for typescript.

As you know the [mysql module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) don't support promise pattern basically.

When I used javascript not typescript, this code worked well.

```
const pool = mysql.createPool(config);
pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query);

export default pool;
```

But, the type of `pool.query` and `util.promisify()` is not matched in typescript.

So I'm trying to add a new property on `interface Pool extends EscapeFunctions` in `node_modules/@types/mysql/index.d.ts`

Should I edit `node_modules/@types/mysql/index.d.ts` file directly?

Or, are there any safe way to this?

Comment: Maybe: `pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query) as any;`?

Comment: @Paleo this works. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, by default `utils.promisify` supports only node.js-styled callbacks, that looks like `(err, result) => void`. Your pool query callback is declared something like `(err, result, fields) => void`. So short answer is, no, by default you cant use it in this case.

But if you are intrested in way, you can extend `utils.promisify` declaration to fit your module declaration, you can write something like this in your project:

```
declare module "util" {
    function promisify<T1, TResult, TFields>(fn: (arg1: T1, callback: (err: any, result: TResult, fields: TFields) => void) => void): () => Promise<{ result: TResult, fields: TFields }>;
}
```

after redeclaring promisify, you now need to extend your `pool.query` to support additional args(as described in [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_custom_promisified_functions)), something like this:

```
pool.query[util.promisify.custom] = <TResult, TFields>(query: string) => new Promise<{ result: TResult, fields: TFields }>((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query(query, (err, result: TResult, fields: TFields) => {
        if (err) { reject(err) }
        else { resolve({ result, fields }) }
    })
});
```

now your promisify supports the module, but it is not so simple, as just declaring promise manually, or even making your own promisify function, that will support any number of arguments for example.

Comment: Thanks, what is util.promisify.custom ?

Comment: It is unique constant value of type ```Symbol```. It can be used as an object key, to determine unique property, avoiding potential interference, like when you use strings as keys for properties. In this case it used to safely add property to ```pool.query``` function.